# After upload app on Play store Facebook Login is can't work show invalid hash key

Tags: android, facebook, hash

I integrate fb login in my app and its works well but when I upload app on play store its give error Invalid hash key. I generate hash key using this command :-

```
keytool -exportcert -alias einvite  -keystore C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\Einvitecode\einvite.jks | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

He asked my keystore password I enter keystore password. After I enter password It show a hash key. I copy hash key and paste its my developer accounts and save its. But when I download my app login Its show Invalid hashkey.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are actually signed apk with einvite.jks and einvite key. If this is correct then open your app in the Facebook Developer console, open App Review and make sure that in your application turned on a public access. By default your app is in Development mode. Maybe this will help

Answer (score 0):

i faced the similar problem don't know why it changed after uploading to the store but I added the new Hash (as mentioned) in the Facebook messaged to the Key Hashes in my app on developers.facebook.com/app//settings/Basic. And now it is working.!